As 'beiseiteschieben' did not officially exist before 2006, why do we treat this (official) new form as primary and call it a "separable" verb?
Dictionaries now have to list it under 'B', along with a number of "new" verbs such as 'beiseitelegen, beiseitestellen/drängen/schubsen/ziehen/führen etc etc. Eradicating the previously official gap between 'beiseite and a following past participle, infinitive or verb in the end position is essentially a spelling change, so why pretend that a whole new set of verbs has been created? Moreover, the gap between a grammatical 'zu' and any of these infinitives also has to be eradicated if 'beiseite' is added, so that it seems to act as a conglomerating agent to produce 'beiseitezuschieben'. As a perfectly normal adverb it should be treated in the same way as 'nachhause', which has not (as yet!) been used to create dozens of new verbs to clog up the 'N' section of our dictionaries.

I disagree at step one: beiseiteschieben is not new, see this math book from 1887 .

... but only officially recognised as correct since 2006 according to my sources ....  ?

The key point here (imho) is that the reform from 2006 reversed several questionable decisions of the reform from 1996, restoring rules in charge before 1996. The state before 1996, however, was that not every rule was written down explicitly (which was one of the reasons that the reformers thought that the reform was necessary).

Found a reference to back up my assumption: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibung_von_1996/Neuerungen#Getrennt-_und_Zusammenschreibung_2

There are a lot of misconceptions at work here:

the same way as 'nachhause'

"Nachhause" is in fact written "nach Hause". "Hause" here is a Dativ (with the old and nowadays mostly unused Dativ-ending "-e") and that is because the Dativ in German took over the function of one of the dropped Kasus in the Proto-Indo-European language, the Lokativ.

Eradicating the previously official gap between 'beiseite and a following past participle, infinitive or verb in the end position is essentially a spelling change, so why pretend that a whole new set of verbs has been created?

It is one of the distinct features of German to be able to create composites out of thin air. Sometimes these composites mean what their constituents suggest, sometimes - not quite. A "Putenschnitzel" is a "Schnitzel" made from "Pute(-nfleisch)", a "Rindsschnitzel" one made from "Rind(-fleisch)", etc. - but a "Kinderschnitzel" is made for, not from children.
Also notice the difference between composites written together or apart, e.g. "viel versprechend" (promising a lot) and "vielversprechend" (very promising). "Hausapotheke" is the medicine cabinet, whereas "Haus Apotheke" is the name of a noble dynasty, like "House Windsor".
Many times the resulting words won't be in any dictionary at all: if I'd speak about a (completely made up):

Verhüttungsabgasreiniger

every German speaker would understand what I talk about (a machine or material to clean the exhausts of smelting processes). From the translation you can see that English needs a complete multi-part phrase to accomplish the same.
And, finally, coming back to "Nachhause": there is e.g. the Nachhauseweg.

Also gory the classic Rapsöl, Olivenöl, Babyöl. Natural language simply is not orthogonal. In all reality, the joke works almost equivalently in English. Bitching about German compounds and then doing exactly the same thing but leaving the words separate just to confuse the reader and make parsing harder seems quite ... hypocritical ;-).

@BlauKakaPOW: honestly - I can't explain and perhaps no native speaker can't either. I could say something like "the better you know German the better your ability to understand those will be" but that doesn't really explain anything (even though being true). See Peters comment below yours - language isn't orthogonal.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica this native English speaker, at least, finds that spaces between the components of a compound make parsing easier, not harder (or, if you prefer, that a noun phrase or verb phrase is easier to parse than a long compound). But maybe that's why you winked.  I occasionally misconstrue German compounds; for example, another answer mentions Fahrradsport, which I might read as Fahrrad + -s + Port.  I imagine that if my German were better this would be less of a problem.

@phoog: your example overlooks the fact that - by the rules of German "Fugenlaute" - a hypothetical word like "Fahrrad + Port" would be spelled "Fahrrad-port" and not "Fahrrad-s-port". A "Fugen-s" would simply be wrong here.

This doesn’t actually answer the question. The core of the question is why certain combinations of preposition + noun used as adverbial adjuncts to modify verbs are fused with the verb, while others aren’t. Why is it beiseiteschieben and auseinanderfallen instead of bei Seite schieben and aus einander fallen; but nach Hause gehen and zu Hause sein instead of nachhausegehen and zuhausesein? There is no structural difference between the two groups; the difference is exclusively one of orthography and – as far as I can tell – entirely arbitrary.

@JanusBahsJacquet: I thought I made that clear: "bei Seite schieben" and "beiseiteschieben" are both possible but they mean different things - like "vielversprechend" and "viel versprechend", which I gave as an example. And this is not arbitrary but "built into" the very core of the German language.

Vielversprechend/viel versprechend is not really a parallel, for several reasons: (1) there is no verb *vielversprechen, only the participle; (2) the two forms are stressed differently; (3) viel is not a PP but a plain adverb, which function differently. Beiseite isn’t the best example since it’s not really used as a regular PP in current-day German, only as an already univerbated adverb, but what exactly would the hypothetical semantic difference between bei (or zur) Seite schieben and beiseiteschieden? Or indeed between nachhausekommen and nach Hause gehen?

Perhaps a better example: what is the semantic difference between zufrieden stellen and zufriedenstellen (a case where Duden says both are permitted and simple variants of each other)?

@JanusBahsJacquet: "zufrieden stellen" is a manner of "stellen", precisely "stellen in a zufrieden manner: "Zufrieden stellte ich den Stuhl dorthin." Contraryly I try to "zufriedenstellen" you by answering your comments, which is a completely different type of activity. Notice that Duden: 1) has no authority; 2) never gives any reason for what they decree; 3) quite often is in disagreement with the results of linguistic research. In short: if Duden says it, so what?

The distinction you are trying to make here is not borne out by actual usage, nor by the official spelling rules; cf. the Wörterverzeichnis (p. 281) where both are listed with a reference to §34 E5 (p. 36): “Lässt sich in einzelnen Fällen keine klare Entscheidung darüber treffen, ob eine idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung vorliegt, so bleibt es dem Schreibenden überlassen, getrennt oder zusammenzuschreiben”. In other words, they are the same.

Obviously, in the example you gave (“Zufrieden stellte ich den Stuhl dorthin”) they are not interchangeable, but that’s because there is no connection at all between zufrieden and stellen in that example – it’s a completely different construction and not relevant to the discussion at all, which is about whether particle verbs should be written as one or two words. Using the base verb in a sentence that happens to also contain a word equivalent to the verbal particle says nothing.

Reminds me of the word "Blumentopferde" - which the brain might parse as "Blumento pferde" or "Blumen topf erde"

German dictionaries traditionally list all compounds when they are somewhat common, even if their meanings are obvious from its parts. As an example, duden.de has "Fahrradschloss, -schlüssel, -schnellweg, -sport, -stadt, -ständer". None of them have surprising meanings. If I recall correctly, all of these are usually in the same paragraph, starting with "Fahrrad" in the printed version.
So it is only consistent to do the same for the compounds with "beiseite".
As for why "beiseite" is treated differently from "nach Hause", we have, according to PONS, Rule 4.5:

Immer zusammengeschrieben werden Verben, die eine Verbpartikel als ersten Bestandteil haben, die auch den Hauptakzent trägt.

"Beiseite" takes the accent, "nach Hause" not not always.
I don't know what your definition of a word is, but given the definition of a word being something you write together, then it was the "spelling change" that created dozens of new words that unfortunately now "clog" up your "B" section. I mean, dictionaries can't just go and pretend these words don't exist.

How exactly would the stress distribution differ between beiˈseiteˌschieben and nach ˈHause ˌgehen? To me, they have identical stress patterns, which isn’t really surprising since they have the same origin: a verb modified by a prepositional phrase consisting of a preposition and a noun in the dative case.

@JanusBahsJacquet Hm, in nach Hause gehen "nach Hause" takes the accent, that's right. Maybe the reasoning should be as follows: Because the meaning of "Seite" faded, bei Seite is beiseite and therefore a particle and the rule applies. In "nach Hause" there is no meaning difference. Furthermore, "nach Hause" does not always do that, like in nach 'Hause 'schicken.

Dictionaries could simply indicate that 'beiseite' et. al. behave in the same way as 'Partikeln' (ab/an/ein/nach etc), instead of trying to list all the possible infinitive forms. In the 100 or more "verbs" beginning 'herum' listed in Collins, from 'herumalbern' to 'herumzigeunern' only one 'herum' means anything other than 'around/about'.
